# Using pyspark window function to calculate aggregated balance with different conditions

Tags: python, pyspark, window-functions

I am writing a pyspark pool application to handle millions of rows of consumption data and doing allocation of different bucket this consumption can go to.

a customer can have multiple payment ids and each payment id can have multiple lots under it which has some prepaid balance assigned to

```
paymentBalances = spark.createDataFrame(
[
    ("C1","Payment1", "Lot1", 50),
    ("C1","Payment1", "Lot2", 150),
    ("C1","Payment2", "Lot3", 100),
    ("C2","Payment3", "Lot4", 100), ........
],
["customerId","paymentId", "lotId","remainingBalance"])
```

and I will have consumption order data coming in as below. these orders will consume the balance lots above. Once the lot balance reaches 0, new orders will not be able to consume from it

```
orders = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("O1", "C1", 'Payment1',100),
        ("O2", "C1", 'Payment1', 200),
        ("O3", "C1", 'Payment2', 30),
        ("O4", "C2", 'Payment3', 150),.......
    ],
    ["orderId", "customerId","paymentId","amount"]
)
```

what I need to derive is how the orders would consume payments

something like

```
    [
        ("O1", "C1", 'Payment1', 100,[{"Lot1":50},{"Lot2": 50})]),// Remaining Amount Lot1:0, Lot2:100
        ("O2", "C1", 'Payment1', 200,[{"Lot2":100},{"overBudget":100}]) // Payment1 is drained fully.
        ("O3", "C1", 'Payment2', 80,[{"Lot3":30},{"overBudget":50}]) // Payment2 is drained fully.
        ("O4", "C2", 'Payment3', 100,[{"Lot4":100}]) // remaining amount Lot4:50
    ],
```

["orderId", "customerId","paymentId","amount","lotAllocations"]

If I join orders with paymentBalances, I can get potential lots available for each order row, and am guessing we would need to partition this by customer as each customer will have his own setof payment balances. But not reallysure how I can keep running balance of each lot and exclude the order from calculation if we have multiple eligible payment lots mapped to it

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand quite well what's your purpose since as you said "a set of potential lots are available for each order row". Once you computed the list of (lot,balance) pairs for each (customer,payment) pair. How do you want to process the data? From your example I get:

```
+----------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------+
|customerId|paymentId|orderId|amount|lots                          |
+----------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------+
|C1        |Payment1 |O1     |100   |{[Lot1, Lot2], [50, 150], 200}|
|C1        |Payment1 |O2     |200   |{[Lot1, Lot2], [50, 150], 200}|
|C1        |Payment2 |O3     |30    |{[Lot3], [100], 100}          |
|C2        |Payment3 |O4     |150   |{[Lot4], [100], 100}          |
+----------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------+
```

`lots` is a structure computed as

```
df_pb = (paymentBalances
         .orderBy('customerId', 'paymentId', 'lotId')
         .groupBy('customerId', 'paymentId')
         .agg(
            F.collect_list(F.col('lotId')).alias('lotIds'),
            F.collect_list(F.col('remainingBalance')).alias('balances'),
            F.sum(F.col('remainingBalance')).alias('totalBalance')
            )
         .withColumn('lots', F.struct(['lotIds','balances', 'totalBalance']))
         .select(['customerId', 'paymentId','lots'])
        )
```

I do not get how the order `O1` is modifying the `lots` struct.

Comment: updated the description: Once an order uses up lot amount, it cannot be cosumed for subequent orders. so after O1 has used up 50 and 50 from Lot1 and Lot2, Lot1 is fully drained and only 150 is available in Lot2 for remaining orders